# Is the ISC kaput

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-software, math-communication

The very useful [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au) is showing me this

> [image: Proxy Error]

What's up?  **multiple choice**

(a) No, it's fine at that address: idiot Edgar did something wrong...

(b) It is off-line at that address, because it is at a new address that ignorant  Edgar does not know about

(c) It is, indeed, not working.  But why?

(c1) It is permanently closed

(c2) University of Newcastle is on break and they haven't noticed it yet

(c3) It is closed while they wait for us users to donate money to make it run

Comment: Which web address did you try? I just tried this one: http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes, the old one at Simon Fraser (oldweb) is OK, but is badly out of date.  The address I used is the one in the link in my question... http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/ where it moved in 2010.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972204/software-techniques-and-tricks-of-experimental-mathematics-to-conjecture-possib  from about ten days ago, I put in jpegs of the thing working properly and address

Comment: So the quitting time is within the last 10 days.

Comment: ISC returned today, October 28.  With a new output format!